# Python Selenium Custom FireFox Profile Not Saving Data

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, binary

So I've been experimenting with a custom firefox profile in my selenium project so that websites don't think I'm a new user every time. This is the code I'm using:

```
profile FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\Scott\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\t3bxt79j.bot_profile') 
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary)
```

This code should link up to my profile that I created and the binary (which is already tested and working). However, every time I go to the website it acts like I'm a new user. None of my bookmarks on this profile are saving either and I'm making sure that I load firefox with the new profile.

Answer (score 0):

It does save, but does not get back to you.
I've answered that just now here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33350778/2480481.

Profile is made to allow you run test with certain personalization of the firefox, settings, extensions, etc, not for save it.

But yes, I miss too a parameter to make it "fixed" instead of temporal.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Good point on the duplicate.  Objection withdrawn, and my mistake acknowledged.  I've flagged the question.

Comment: @Prune Nice, cheers.