# Use existing open tab and url in Selenium py

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I'm trying to use Selenium python to use a url that is already open on Internet Explorer. I had a look around and not sure if this is possible.

The reason why I wouldn't like to open new brower or tab is because the page changes to different text.

So far my text only opens a new browser
**CODE**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get("https://outlook.live.com/owa/")
```

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Ie()` will create a new instance of browser which will open a new browser window and stores the window id. The second line you wrote will open the url in the opened window.

Comment: As per my knowledge, selenium will only interact with those windows, that are invoked by it but not on those which were already open. Please correct me if i was wrong, once you get solid confirmation from a trusted source.

Comment: Ahh thanks that would make sense since I could't find documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37274741/6335604) helped me with same problem.

By now you can not access previously opened tabs with selenium.
But you can try to recreate your session, passing what is needed using requests library, for example.