# Python Selenium Webdriver Restore Previous Session

Tags: python, selenium, session, firefox

To skip 2FA to an account I would like to save session in one Firefox Profile and everytime opening the browser it will open that profile and session.

To achieve this I have changed settings of Firefox profile to "Show your windows and tabs from last time". Now, whenever I am opening this profile manually it always the page I closed last time with session.

Now whenever I am doing the same thing from python selenium it is not opening the page last time closed. If I browse to the same page then it is asking for password. But again if I manually chick "Restore previous session" then it loads previous session.

I tried several ways but none worked. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is related to session cookies vs persistent cookies which is addressed in ["Selenium use of firefox profile"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37274741/8708630)