# How to prevent geckodriver+selenium (python) to open new instance of firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

When opening new instance of *Firefox* using selenium and geckodriver, it opens a  brand new Firefox instance. What I want is for the instance opened to be related to my current Firefox browser i.e. the websites i have logged into my browser. I would like the same configuration to stay in new instance opened using **gecko** and **selenium**.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://mail.google.com')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium use of firefox profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247336/selenium-use-of-firefox-profile)

Comment: @JeffC : I think he is asking about reconnection with previous session.

Comment: @cruisepandey I thought maybe so too but this, "I would like the same configuration to stay **in new instance opened**", convinced me otherwise. Either way, this question has been answered before. He will have to clarify the question if it's not either of these questions.