# how to download a .msi file in chrome using selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

[image: download error]

How to avoid this issue using selenium and python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up)

Comment: Hi @Ketan have you fixed this one ? can you provide if there is any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set [Selenium profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247336/selenium-use-of-firefox-profile) to enable downloading without asking:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/octet-stream')
profile.set_preference("browser.safebrowsing.enabled", 'false')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://yourpage.com")
```

`"application/octet-stream"` is the file type, check [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) if you don't know your file type

With chrome you should be able to use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test", # Insert the path where you want your files to be saved!
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331854/downloading-a-file-at-a-specified-location-through-python-and-selenium-using-chr) for some more informations

Comment: This is with firefox can you give some solution with chrome browser?

Comment: @KetanGupta Updated the answer

Comment: what it means "not working"? which error is returned?

Comment: Some file not found 2 exceptions were there

Comment: After these lines of code do i have to add anything any where?

Comment: In the line `"download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",` you have to sobstitute the path `C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test` with the path where you want the file to be saved

Comment: options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\<username>\Downloads",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

web_driver = webdriver.Chrome("WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe")

Comment: where did you take `web_driver = webdriver.Chrome("WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe")`? Erase that line and use `driver` where you where using `web_driver`

Comment: with the firefox also its not working same error is coming