# How can I use saved cookies with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to make a tool that does things on your website account. Some things use reCAPTCHA after you log in, so I want to know how I could use the firefox's saved cookies the are on the normal browser on selenium so that it skips the reCAPTCHA and assumes you're not a bot.

Comment: You're looking for [selenium profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247336/selenium-use-of-firefox-profile)