# Python Selenium Custom FireFox Profile keep data without discarding them after session

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

i have a website that i want to login to and it should stay like that for multiple sessions

I tried pickle to save cookies once logged in and then load the cookies when running the script again

but this doesn't work the website logs me out

So i tried to set custom profile for firefox 
but checking which profile its running on by adding code

```
# 2- get tmp file location
profiletmp = driver.firefox_profile.path

# but... the current profile is a copy of the original profile :/
print("running profile " + profiletmp)
```

shows me that i'm running in a tmp directory copied from the main profile mentioned `/tmp/xxxxxxxx/webdriver-py-copy`

so according to the answer here ([Python / Selenium / Firefox: Can't start firefox with specified profile path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435749/python-selenium-firefox-cant-start-firefox-with-specified-profile-path/33350778#33350778)) i tried copying the folder to main profile but still when loading browser all changes are lost (ex; i made a bookmark and logged into a site then copied the folder over to main profile replacing all the files but still when opening firefox all changes are lost)
i can only retain changes if i manually use Firefox profile and then login without geckodriver now when gecko driver loads the page i'm logged in

by adding custom profile location in chromedriver it retains data but i have different issues with chrome and i want to use firefox